# Kivy class factory error

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I tried to make a program with a screen manager an images you can click on.
I first I tried to store the kivy file within a string variable and return the string variable, but I got this error message:

```
 kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <BILD1>
```

So I tried to return the Screenmanager, but it did not seem to work.
I still got the same error message, could you please help me.
Here is the rest of my source code:

```
class Auswahl(Screen):
    pass
class Frage(Screen):
    farbe = ListProperty([1, 1, 1, 1])
    def druck(self):
        self.farbe = ([1, 0, 0, 1])
        self.ids.box1.clear_widgets()
        wimg = Image(source='Bild1.png')
        self.ids.box1.add_widget(wimg)

class Troll(Screen):
    pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

Builder.load_file('turf.kv')

class BILD1(Widget):
    velocity = ListProperty([1, 0])
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Knopf, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.Update, 1/60.)
    def Update(self, *args):
        pass
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print 'es geht'
class BILD2(Knopf):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print 'es geht'
class BILD3(Knopf):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print 'es geht'
class BILD4(Knopf):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print 'es geht'



class TurF(App):
    def build(self):
        return Manager()

TurF().run()
```

Comment: Post a working example of some code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your Builder.load_file('turf.kv') like so:

```
class Auswahl(Screen):
    pass
class Frage(Screen):
    farbe = ListProperty([1, 1, 1, 1])
    def druck(self):
        self.farbe = ([1, 0, 0, 1])
        self.ids.box1.clear_widgets()
        wimg = Image(source='Bild1.png')
        self.ids.box1.add_widget(wimg)

class Troll(Screen):
    pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass



class BILD1(Widget):
    velocity = ListProperty([1, 0])
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Knopf, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.Update, 1/60.)
    def Update(self, *args):
        pass
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print 'es geht'
class BILD2(Knopf):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print 'es geht'
class BILD3(Knopf):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print 'es geht'
class BILD4(Knopf):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print 'es geht'



Builder.load_file('turf.kv')

class TurF(App):
    def build(self):
        return Manager()

TurF().run()
```